# Keep emulated javascript terminal window on webpage in fixed location

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to learn some javascript and css. To to this I've forked som code and are trying to paste it together with some of my own idea. You can see my page were i work here: [web page for learning](http://eriksore.github.io)
I've reached a problem. I'm using a javascript I've forked to emulate a terminal like interface. This is called `jsterm`. I also have a box a the bottom of the page with some share options and flairs. I would like to make these 'static' so that the `jsterm` emulated terminal doesn't go underneath the box at the bottom. Where should I attack this? I've tried changing the `height:` value in css but `jsterm` still covers the full page.

```
div.jsterm {
background: black;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 16px;
color: #E0E0E0;
top:0%;
left:0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.share_box{
display: inline;
position:fixed;
height: 10%;
width:100%;
bottom:0%;
left:0%;
border:3px solid #a1a1a1;
background:#FFF;
padding:15px;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>Erik Sorensen</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
      <meta name="description" content="Erik's webpage">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='cmd_box'>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/commands/com1.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/config/config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsterm.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="share_box">
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" data-via="eriksor">Tweet</a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <!-- Google + -->
    <g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
        </script>
    <!--Stackoverflow flair -->
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2394561/eriksorensen">
        <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2394561.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for ErikSorensen at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for ErikSorensen at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
    </a>
</div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: give us the html as well

Comment: Maybe you got an inline style inside the div.jsterm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer, after @jascha poked me somewhat in the right direction.

changed `margin-bottom: 20px;` to `margin-bottom: 10%;` for `jsterm`

Answer (score 0):

the link to github links to eriksire. instead of eriksore. ;)

to get scrollbars and the .jsterm div to adhere to the height you set try:

```
.jsterm {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to get the console to always be above the share_box, making the share box disappear on smaller resolutions:

```
.jsterm {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
.share_box {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I've edited link. Sry about that. No, it still doesn't work as expected. But I got a scroll bar though ;-)

Comment: i updated my answer, if that still does not solve what you want to solve i need a better explanation of your goals :)